# multiple links per row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have a MySQL database in which each row represents an episode of a podcast. I would like to include show notes for each episode and therefore need to be able to extract multiple links per row via PHP.

What would be the best data field to achieve this? I'm thinking that including the links via a linked table may be the only way to do this, but if anybody knows a simpler way I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Your idea might very well be what you are looking for. If you want it a bit simpler, you might add a list of links associated to an episode, i.e. a single row, as an additional CLOB-field and store a serialized array in there (either php serialize or JSON-notation). Your question is a bit vague, as to whether you want these links to be something like a description for each episode or more like a tag, i.e. be able to find episodes linking to the same page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using a new table (`podcast_link`) because the number of links per podcast is flexible. Adding a `text` field to the `podcast` table wouldn't be very efficient due to the parsing of the links when you want to display them.
This will also allow you to e.g. count the number of links per podcast, so you can display "Show related links (4)" and you can add more fields to the links, so that you don't only display the links, but also a title for the link. Especially going forward you might want to add more information per link.

Comment: This is definitely the most appealing way to me. You're right, it opens up extension capabilities at a later date too.

Comment: The performance difference between parsing a few links in PHP and a more complex MySQL-query using JOIN is probably ignorable (if it even exists). Also counting links and providing a title is also possible when using serializing/unserializing a PHP-array. I agree, that using an additional table is more future proof, i.e. offers additional functionality, e.g. show which episodes refer to the same link or how many episodes use a link, but your examples do not show benefits of this, as they are equally doable with just an additional field.

Comment: Using a serialized array requires you to parse the full array everytime, even if you just want to show the count, as opposed to doing the count in the query. Also this is the basics of normalization, making data more accessible, usable and manageable. "your examples do not show benefits of this" - You can't expect me to list the full capabilities of databases I hope..

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` Function :

> You have to save your links for example with this structure : 
>   `http:\\example.com\podcast01.mp3,http:\\example.com\podcast02.mp3,http:\\example.com\podcast03.mp3` in the database rows.

then when you want to extract them you can easily use `explode()` function with this way :

```
$links= $row['links']; // your links in row 
$links_array = explode("," , $links);// now you have an array that you can easily access to each block of it.
```

for example :

```
echo ($links_array[0]);// output : http:\\example.com\podcast01.mp3
```

good luck

Comment: And what happens if one of the links contains a comma?

Comment: this is simple example ! you can use some spacial , i use `|` for myself or space between links .

Comment: This is a good suggestion but I think I'm going to go with the separate table concept in one of the other answers.

Comment: Ok , i recommend you to use Richard solution , but don't forget to index your table , it make your queries faster.